# Runtime of SubArray equalling a sum

Tags: algorithm

Recently I came across this C code to find the integers in an array equalling a sum.

```
int subArraySum(int arr[], int n, int sum)

{

/* Initialize curr_sum as value of first element
   and starting point as 0 */
int curr_sum = arr[0], start = 0, i;

/* Add elements one by one to curr_sum and if the curr_sum exceeds the
   sum, then remove starting element */
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    // If curr_sum exceeds the sum, then remove the starting elements
    while (curr_sum > sum && start < i-1)
    {
        curr_sum = curr_sum - arr[start];
        start++;
    }

    // If curr_sum becomes equal to sum, then return true
    if (curr_sum == sum)
    {
        printf ("Sum found between indexes %d and %d", start, i-1);
        return 1;
    }

    // Add this element to curr_sum
    if (i < n)
      curr_sum = curr_sum + arr[i];
}

// If we reach here, then no subarray
printf("No subarray found");
return 0;

}
```

My questions the run time of this algorithm is given as O(n) which can be proved by counting the number of operations performed on every element of arr[] in worst case. As far I can see it looks like a O(n^2) algorithm. May be I missed to learn something but can anybody explain how this is O(n), if at all this is O(n).

Answer (score 2):

it is `O(n)` because you have the for loop the run `n` times and the while loop the can be replaced in an `if` statement. `start` is starting as 0 and doesn't ever assigned except for

```
start++;
```

in the loop. meaning max of `n` times you are going to be inside the `while` loop

Comment: The line " max of n times you are going to be inside the while loop " nailed it.